# Cannot create android app from an archive containing both DEX and Java-bytecode content

Tags: android, android-studio, android-r8

Thanks in advance for helping here, as I've been stuck in the mud for a couple of days now with the following error below:

```
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.R8Task$R8Runnable
   > Cannot create android app from an archive containing both DEX and Java-bytecode content.
aused by: com.android.tools.r8.internal.Ub: Cannot create android app from an archive containing both DEX and Java-bytecode content.
    at com.android.tools.r8.ArchiveProgramResourceProvider.getProgramResources(R8_8.1.68_081071c36a35dea9a8e7845c23af618c2d62fb486760a022308124c1698d2e82:24)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.R8ProgramResourceProvider.addProgramResourceProvider(r8Tool.kt:470)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.R8Tool.runR8(r8Tool.kt:237)
```

I'm not sure if it's about a java library that is messing things up.
AGP version : 8.1.4
Gradle Version : 8.3

These are the files:

build.gradle.kts

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("dagger.hilt.android.plugin")


}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.fittestapp"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.fittestapp"
        minSdk = 34
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
        multiDexEnabled = true

    }

    buildTypes {

        debug {
            isMinifyEnabled = true
            isShrinkResources = true
            multiDexEnabled = true
        }
        release {
            isShrinkResources = true
            isMinifyEnabled = true
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
            multiDexEnabled = true
        }
    }




    configurations {
        all { // You should exclude one of them not both of them
            // exclude (group= "org.jetbrains.kotlin", module= "kotlin-compiler-embeddable")
            exclude(group = "net.sf.kxml", module = "kxml2")
            exclude(group = "org.jetbrains.kotlin", module = "kotlin-build-statistics")
            exclude(group = "org.jetbrains.kotlin", module = "kotlin-build-tools-api")
            exclude(group = "org.jetbrains.kotlin", module = "kotlin-gradle-plugin")
            exclude(group = "xmlpull", module = "xmlpull")
            exclude(group = "xmlpull", module = "xpp3")
            exclude(group = "xpp3", module = "xpp3")
            exclude(group = "com.google.dagger", module = "hilt-android-compiler")
            exclude(group = "com.google.dagger", module = "hilt-compiler")
            exclude(group = "com.android.tools.build", module = "builder")
            exclude(group = "jakarta.activation", module = "jakarta.activation-api")

        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf(
            "-Xstring-concat=inline"
        )
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.6"

    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1,DEPENDENCIES,public-suffix-list.txt}"
            excludes += "/**/*.txt"
            excludes += "kotlin/coroutines/coroutines.kotlin_builtins"
            excludes += "xsd/catalog.xml"
            excludes += "META-INF/mimetypes.default"
            excludes += "kotlin/kotlin.kotlin_builtins"
            excludes += "kotlin/reflect/reflect.kotlin_builtins"
            excludes += "kotlin/collections/collections.kotlin_builtins"
            excludes += "META-INF/mailcap.default"
            excludes += "META-INF/LICENSE.md"
            excludes += "META-INF/NOTICE.md"
            excludes += "META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties"
            excludes += "kotlin/annotation/annotation.kotlin_builtins"
            excludes += "META-INF/INDEX.LIST"
            excludes += "kotlin/internal/internal.kotlin_builtins"
            excludes += "kotlin/ranges/ranges.kotlin_builtins"
            excludes += "META-INF/gradle/incremental.annotation.processors"

        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.2")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.10.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3-window-size-class:1.1.2")

    implementation("androidx.room:room-common:2.6.0")
    implementation("javax.inject:javax.inject:1")
    implementation("androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:1.6.0-beta01")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime-ktx:2.7.5")

    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-compose:1.1.0-alpha13")
    implementation("com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:5.0.0-rc01")
    implementation("androidx.work:work-testing:2.9.0-rc01")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.7.0-rc01")

    implementation("androidx.work:work-runtime:2.8.1")
    implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-work:1.1.0")
    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.49")
    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-testing:2.49")
    implementation("com.google.dagger.hilt.android:com.google.dagger.hilt.android.gradle.plugin:2.49")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-viewbinding:1.5.4")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.1")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.5")
    implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.1.0")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.7.5")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:2.0.0-Beta1")
    implementation(platform("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:2.0.0-Beta1"))
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-build-tools-api:2.0.0-Beta1")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-native-utils:2.0.0-Beta1")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.2.0-alpha13")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-android:1.6.0-beta02")
    implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03")
    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.49")
    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.49")
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-blockstore:16.2.0")
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1")
    implementation("androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1")
    implementation("com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.3.0-alpha17")
    implementation("com.github.bumptech.glide:compose:1.0.0-beta01")

    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")

    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.10.00"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
}
```

build.gradle.kts (module)

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.1.4" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.21" apply false
    id("androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin") version "2.7.5" apply false
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.49" apply false
}
```

I'm unsure if I should share anything else, but please let me know.

Comment: I've been unable to reproduce the issue you described above. It also looks like the stack trace you have posted is truncated and there is a missing stack between the message and the "aused by:".

Would it be possible for you to create a small reproduction project and upload in the [R8 issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/317330821) such that we can reproduce this?

Answer (score 1):

I've filed [b/317330821](https://issuetracker.google.com/317330821) in the D8/R8 issue tracker. The issue you have is some dependency that includes both DEX and Java bytecode and the compiler does not know how to handle that as only one of them is likely supposed to be included as part of the program.

The compiler should provide information about which input is causing this, but from your error message it appears to not be the case. Filed [b/317330821](https://issuetracker.google.com/317330821) to address that.